# ASP.Net Linq Databinding not showing data as expected

Tags: asp.net, linq, data-binding

I'm trying to databind some information to a repeater but it seems to be showing me the data but not in the way i'd expect

Here's the data i'm getting

```
     Value      Xml      HasAttributes    HasElements     IsEmpty    Value
         1        1              False          False       False        1
12/12/2006        1              False          False       False        1
```

But the data I want to get is something like this

```
     ADULTS         DEPARTURE_DATE
          1             12/12/2006
```

Here's my LINQ and ASP.Net

```
Dim xel = XElement.Parse(xmlstring)

Dim flights = xel.Descendants("Flights")            
Dim tests = flights.Where(Function(f) DateTime _
.Parse(f.Descendants("DEPARTURE_DATE").Value).Date <= DateTime.Now.Date) _
.OrderBy(Function(f) f.Descendants("DEPARTURE_DATE").Value)_
.ThenBy(Function(f) f.Descendants("DEPARTURE_TIME").Value)

CType(e.Item.FindControl("Repeater"), Repeater).DataSource = tests  _ 
.Descendants().Elements()
CType(e.Item.FindControl("Repeater"), Repeater).DataBind()
```

Here's some sample XML

```
<booking>
    <travel>
        <flights>
            <flight id="1">
                <adults>1</adults>
                <departure_date>12/12/2006</departure_date>
                <departure_time>08:05</departure_time>
            </flight>
        </flights>
    </travel>
</booking>
```

The string `xmlstring` is the XML above.

Here's my repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DEPARTURE_DATE") %>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

It just keeps saying that there is no field DEPARTURE_DATE in the datasource

Any ideas how this is possible if it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your query to something like this...

```
.Select(Function(f)  new with { .DEPARTURE_DATE = f.Descendants("DEPARTURE_DATE").Value })
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code with this

```
 <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DEPARTURE_DATE") %>
```

Else
Change your query

```
.select(p=> new DATE =DEPARTURE_DATE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - the top one doesn't work it was my mistake for putting the wrong field name in the post - the 2nd one I can't get to work either it just keeps saying Expression expected?